# What is the purpose of creating an instance of Interface only?

Tags: java, interface

What I know about interfaces is that:

1) Interfaces are list of methods i.e Template

2) Interface type can refer to an object of class which implements that interface.

Today I came across below code

```
interface Test  
{  
  void greet();  
}  
public class Demo  
{  
  public static void main(String[] args)  
  {  
    Test t = new Test()  ---> Is it correct ? WHY ?
     {  
       public void greet()  
       {  
         System.out.print("\nHi, Best wishes to way2java.com\n");  
       }  
    };  
    t.greet();  
    }  
}
```

Am not able understand the intention of below code snippet

```
Test t = new Test()
```

1) Do Interfaces have constructors ? My knowledge says Interfaces are having only methods lists but not a definition

2) Is it legal to create a object of Interface ? My knowledge says, the interface type can only refer to an object of class which implements that interface.

3) If its legal then whats the purpose ?

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is the format for an inline implements. Because they are both calling a new instance of it and then implementing the method list defined in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, they don't.

2) No.

What you are creating here is **an anonymous class that implements your interface** - notice that you were forced to implement the `greet` method.

There are situations in your code when you simply do not care about giving your implementation a particular name - then you can pass the anonymous inner class - the whole concept of lambda expressions in Java is based on this.

Let's say you want to print the content of a list using the `forEach` method:

```
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)
  .forEach(...);
```

The `forEach` accepts a `Consumer` instance which is an interface. So, you could either create your own class:

```
class IntegerPrinter implements Consumer<Integer> {

@Override
public void accept(Integer integer) {
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

but that's too trivial to create a new class for it, so it is possible to pass an anonymous instance instead:

```
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)
  .forEach(new Consumer<Integer>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(Integer integer) {
          System.out.println(integer);
      }
  });
```

A little bit better but still quite verbose. This is where lambda expressions come in handy:

```
 Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)
   .forEach(integer -> System.out.println(integer));
```

Comment: Anonymous class here you mean, any random class(In this case its Test) which JVM creates if we create an instance like that. In back-end some random class always present which is implementing Test interface. We do it in this way to reduce efforts for creating a new class which is implementing that(Test) interface. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @LearnJava Yes, but at the end of the day, you are implementing it anyway but you are not giving that class a name.